# For loop between dataframes with calculation and print

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have some difficulties with a for loop that I want to use to link between data from 2 different dataframes.
I am going to show a part of each dataframe, but you need to know that the length of these dataframes is much larger, therefore I need to fix my problem by using a loop. I can't put in images, because I am new here, so I will try to make it clear by typing out a small part:

Dataframe 1:

```
Four columns: Treenr, X, Y and d    
first row: 1, 191.5, 240, 23.93    
second row: 2, 213.5, 153.5, 8.14
```

Dataframe 2

```
Three columns: Liananr, Xl, Yl     
first row: 1, 191.5, 240, 23.93    
second row: 2, 213.5, 153.5, 8.14
```

`X` and `Y` are coordinates.
`d` is a distance.
Eventually I want to calculate for every liana this: `r = sqrt((Xl-X)^2+(Yl-Y)^2)`. I would want this in a new dataframe, that gives me 4 columns:

```
Liananr, Treenr, r and d.
```

This should give 10 rows, because for each liananr (5) linked to Treenr (2)
Respectively this gives for each column the following rows:

```
row 1: 1, 1, 91.11, 23.93    
row 2: 2, 1, 73.56, 29.93    
row 3: 3, 1, 73.56, 29.93    
row 4: 4, 1, 73.56, 29.93    
row 5: 5, 1, 55.22, 23.93    
row 6: 1, 2, 53.50, 8.14    
row 7: 2, 2, 58.22, 8.14    
row 8: 3, 2, 58.22, 8.14    
row 9: 4, 2, 58.22, 8.14    
row 10: 5, 2, 74.50, 8.14
```

I would call the new dataframe 'Linked' and first I define:

```
X <- dataframe1$X    
Y <- dataframe1$Y    
Xl <- dataframe2$Xl    
Yl <- dataframe2$Yl   

for (i in 1:length(dataframe1$Treenr) {    
  for (j in 1:length(dataframe2$Liananr) {    
    Linked$Liananr <- dataframe2$Liananr    
    Linked$Treenr <- dataframe1$Treenr    
    Linked$r <- sqrt((Xl[j,]-X[i,])^2+(Yl[j,]-Y[i,])^2)    
    Linked$d <- dataframe1$d    
  }   
}
```

My biggest problem is that I don't know how to work with i and j in this loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the cross join that returns all combination pairings between two sets (i.e., [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)). This avoids the nested `for` loops as calculations can be handled column-wise. Below example adjusted the figures in df1 as your posted data duplicated data for both frames:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Treenr=c(1,2),
              X=c(181.5, 206.5),
              Y=c(230, 147.5),
              d=c(13.93, 1.14))
df1$key <- 1
df2 <- data.frame(Liananr=c(1,2),
                  X1=c(191.5, 213.5),
                  Y1=c(240, 153.5),
                  d=c(23.93, 8.14))
df2$key <- 1

crossdf <- merge(df1, df2, by='key')
crossdf
#   key Treenr     X     Y   d.x Liananr    X1    Y1   d.y
# 1   1      1 181.5 230.0 13.93       1 191.5 240.0 23.93
# 2   1      1 181.5 230.0 13.93       2 213.5 153.5  8.14
# 3   1      2 206.5 147.5  1.14       1 191.5 240.0 23.93
# 4   1      2 206.5 147.5  1.14       2 213.5 153.5  8.14
crossdf$r <- with(crossdf, sqrt((X1-X)^2+(Y1-Y)^2))

finaldf <- crossdf[c('Liananr', 'Treenr', 'r', 'd.y')]
names(finaldf)[4] <- 'd'
finaldf
#   Liananr Treenr         r     d
# 1       1      1 14.142136 23.93
# 2       2      1 82.923157  8.14
# 3       1      2 93.708324 23.93
# 4       2      2  9.219544  8.14
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this makes it a lot easier!

Comment: Great! If answer helped, please accept to confirm resolution.